# Linux copy all content of a directory to Another directory via Bash, String Manipulation

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My question is very simple and I'm ashamed of myself for asking such a question like this, but I'm trying to learn Linux and I can't find a way to use these strings.

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE = '/home/admins/tryA'
DESTINATION = '/home/admins/tryB'

cp -r '$SOURCE'/* '$DESTINATION'

#cp -r /home/admins/tryA/* /home/admins/tryB
```

As in the comment line, the command works when I don't use variables, but I get an error when I use the variables. Can you briefly tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Error is this:

```
./run.sh: line 4: =: command not found
./run.sh: line 5: =: command not found
cp: target '' is not a directory
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You have several errors, but if you paste your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), it will show all of them.

Comment: In addition, consider to use the option `-a` or `-p` for `cp` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just take away the ' ' around the variables in the cp command

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE=/home/admins/tryA
DESTINATION=/home/admins/tryB

cp -r $SOURCE/* $DESTINATION
```